# library(Rcmdr) でエラー: ‘Rcmdr’ という名前のパッケージはありません

Tags: r

プログラミングに関して素人もいいところなのですが
腸内細菌の研究をやる必要がありqiime2を使用しています。
解析途中で躓いてしまい教えていただけたらと思います。

denoiseの作業のところで、以前は問題なくできていたのですが
別のことでezRをダウンロードしてから？（関係あるかわかりませんが）
ストップするようになってしまいました。
`--verbose` でエラーをみると

```
(qiime2-2021.2) ユーザー名@MacBook-Air start2 % qiime dada2 denoise-paired --i-demultiplexed-seqs paired-end-demux.qza --o-table table.qza --o-representative-sequences rep-seqs.qza --p-trim-left-f 17 --p-trim-left-r 21 --p-trunc-len-f 280 --p-trunc-len-r 250 --o-denoising-stats stats-dada2.qza --verbose
Running external command line application(s). This may print messages to stdout and/or stderr.
The command(s) being run are below. These commands cannot be manually re-run as they will depend on temporary files that no longer exist.

Command: run_dada_paired.R /var/folders/_6/sz481stn0wd8c75djm0kql6m0000gn/T/tmpsazbpz18/forward /var/folders/_6/sz481stn0wd8c75djm0kql6m0000gn/T/tmpsazbpz18/reverse /var/folders/_6/sz481stn0wd8c75djm0kql6m0000gn/T/tmpsazbpz18/output.tsv.biom /var/folders/_6/sz481stn0wd8c75djm0kql6m0000gn/T/tmpsazbpz18/track.tsv /var/folders/_6/sz481stn0wd8c75djm0kql6m0000gn/T/tmpsazbpz18/filt_f /var/folders/_6/sz481stn0wd8c75djm0kql6m0000gn/T/tmpsazbpz18/filt_r 280 250 17 21 2.0 2.0 2 independent consensus 1.0 1 1000000

 library(Rcmdr) でエラー:  ‘Rcmdr’ という名前のパッケージはありません 
 実行が停止されました 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ユーザー名/opt/miniconda3/envs/qiime2-2021.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/q2_dada2/_denoise.py", line 264, in denoise_paired
    run_commands([cmd])
  File "/Users/ユーザー名/opt/miniconda3/envs/qiime2-2021.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/q2_dada2/_denoise.py", line 36, in run_commands
    subprocess.run(cmd, check=True)
  File "/Users/ユーザー名/opt/miniconda3/envs/qiime2-2021.2/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 438, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['run_dada_paired.R', '/var/folders/_6/sz481stn0wd8c75djm0kql6m0000gn/T/tmpsazbpz18/forward', '/var/folders/_6/sz481stn0wd8c75djm0kql6m0000gn/T/tmpsazbpz18/reverse', '/var/folders/_6/sz481stn0wd8c75djm0kql6m0000gn/T/tmpsazbpz18/output.tsv.biom', '/var/folders/_6/sz481stn0wd8c75djm0kql6m0000gn/T/tmpsazbpz18/track.tsv', '/var/folders/_6/sz481stn0wd8c75djm0kql6m0000gn/T/tmpsazbpz18/filt_f', '/var/folders/_6/sz481stn0wd8c75djm0kql6m0000gn/T/tmpsazbpz18/filt_r', '280', '250', '17', '21', '2.0', '2.0', '2', 'independent', 'consensus', '1.0', '1', '1000000']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ユーザー名/opt/miniconda3/envs/qiime2-2021.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/q2cli/commands.py", line 329, in __call__
    results = action(**arguments)
  File "<decorator-gen-522>", line 2, in denoise_paired
  File "/Users/ユーザー名/opt/miniconda3/envs/qiime2-2021.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qiime2/sdk/action.py", line 245, in bound_callable
    output_types, provenance)
  File "/Users/ユーザー名/opt/miniconda3/envs/qiime2-2021.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qiime2/sdk/action.py", line 390, in _callable_executor_
    output_views = self._callable(**view_args)
  File "/Users/ユーザー名/opt/miniconda3/envs/qiime2-2021.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/q2_dada2/_denoise.py", line 279, in denoise_paired
    " and stderr to learn more." % e.returncode)
Exception: An error was encountered while running DADA2 in R (return code 1), please inspect stdout and stderr to learn more.

Plugin error from dada2:

  An error was encountered while running DADA2 in R (return code 1), please inspect stdout and stderr to learn more.
```

Rをいじったりしてからということで

```
library(Rcmdr) でエラー: ‘Rcmdr’ という名前のパッケージはありません
```

これがなにか関係しているのかもと思いezRを消去したのち再度インストールなどをしても治りません。
ちなみにRのコンソールにも同じ文言がでるようになりました。

なにか対処法などご存知の方がいたらお教えいただけたらと思います。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Rcmdrがないというエラーだと思いますが, ezRではなくRcmdrのインストールは試しましたか?

Comment: RcmdrのインストールというのはCRANからのpkgのインストールということですよね？　一度消したのちにインストールしているのですが、起動するとRコンソール内にも同じ文言がでてきます　　　　Error in library(Rcmdr) : there is no package called ‘Rcmdr’
[R.app GUI 1.76 (7976) aarch64-apple-darwin20]

[履歴が次のファイルから読み込まれました /Users/ユーザー名/.Rapp.history]

Comment: すいませんよくわかっていなかったです。　コンソール立ち上げたのちRcmdrのインストールもしましたが結局うまくいきませんでした。そもそも別のPCでqiime2を動かしたりしていたときはqiime2以外のものをダウンロードもしていなかったのですが、、

Comment: 私もRは使いますがezR/Rcmdrやqiime2は使ってないのであまり詳しくないのですが, qiime2 は具体的にどの方法でインストールしましたか? またezRはこの方法に沿ってインストールしたものでしょうか? https://www.jichi.ac.jp/saitama-sct/SaitamaHP.files/statmedOSX.html

Comment: qiime2 はここに書かれているような miniconda  を使用した方法でインストールしたのでしょうか? https://docs.qiime2.org/2021.4/install/native/

Comment: ezR、qiime2ともに記載いただいたアドレスでの方法でインストールしました。思い当たるとすると、ezRのHPの最後のあたりにある、ターミナルに以下のコマンドの設定をしてからおかしくなった？気もしていますが関係しているかはわかりません　　　　　## Starts here
echo "options(Rcmdr=list(plugins='RcmdrPlugin.EZR'))" >> ~/.Rprofile
echo "library(Rcmdr)" >> ~/.Rprofile
echo "local({" >> ~/.Rprofile
echo "old <- getOption('defaultPackages')" >> ~/.Rprofile
echo "options(defaultPackages = c(old, 'Rcmdr'))" >> ~/.Rprofile
echo "})" >> ~/.Rprofile
## Ends here

Answer (score 1):

返信が遅れてすいません.

`~/.Rprofile` のEZR関係の記述を消して使用してください. EZR も併用したい場合は, Rcmdr 起動のたびにウィンドウから「プラグイン読み込み」を選ぶか, [EZRの公式チュートリアル](https://www.jichi.ac.jp/saitama-sct/SaitamaHP.files/manual.html)にあるような起動コマンドをスクリプトやエイリアスとして保存することになると思います.

> ezRのHPの最後のあたりにある、ターミナルに以下のコマンドの設定をしてからおかしくなった？

という疑念はおそらく正しく, `~/.Rprofile` のこの設定はどうやらEZR用に修正した Rcmdr のプログラムを上書きする形で読み込ませているようです. EZRはほぼ国内でのみの通用のため qiime2 開発側は想定しておらず, かつEZR側も他ソフトとの競合を考慮していないようなのでこのような事が起こっているのだと思います.

(EZR をあまり使ってないだけでなく) qiime2 にも生物学にも詳しくないので `denoise-paired` の入力データの形式がわからず, 代わりに[公式チュートリアル](https://docs.qiime2.org/2021.4/tutorials/fmt/)を参考に `denoise-single` を試してみだけですが, 同様のエラーが発生し, `.Rprofile` の記述を消すと動作することを確認したため, このように結論します.

Comment: ありがとうございます。最初は.Rprofileの開き方もわかりませんでしたが、なんとか開いてみて加えたコマンド部分を削除してもうまくいかず、いったん中の記述を全部消してみましたが、今度は 　　エラー:  パッケージ 'compiler' は名前空間を持っていません 
 実行が停止されました ”というメッセージが表示されるようになってしまいました。。再度R自体を削除していれなおしても.Rprofileの中身は消えたままで元々何が書かれていたかもわからず、そもそも中を消したことが関係しているかもわかりませんが。

Comment: `.Rprofile` はデフォルトだと空白 or そもそも存在しないと思うので, そこは問題ないと思います. compiler は基本パッケージの1つで, 通常の方法でインストールした場合は必ず同梱されているはずです. そうなるとそちらが実際にどのようにRをインストールしたのかが気になります. Rを再度, 適切にアンインストールしてから再インストールすることはできますか? また, その手順を教えてください (参考にしたページ等)

Comment: 念の為, 最新のRをインストールできているかも確認してください. 私の場合は上記の結果を Mac Catalina 上で R 4.1.0 で確認しています. 例えば公式のファイル以外でインストールした場合はなんとか方法を思い出して一旦完全に消去してみてください https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。https://blog.statsbeginner.net/entry/2017/10/26/202400 を参考に先ほどRをアンインストールし、念の為qiime2も入れ直して試してみたところ無事に動きました！　R自体は元々提示いただいたアドレスからインストールしてはいましたが、再インストールはしばらくやめておきます　　周りに聞ける人もいなくqiime2forumでも相手にされず困り果てていましたが本当に助かりました。重ね重ねありがとうございます。